# how to start nc over a remote machine in a screen

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, jenkins

I have a requirement to start nc on remote machine in screen and start transfer of file from another remote machine in screen, I am trying to run this through deploy machine(jenkins) with bash script

on remote machine 1 i.e tester1 :

```
ssh -tt mysql@tester1 'screen -d -m nc -l -w 60 5555 | tar xvif -'
```

on remote machine 2 i.e tester2 :

```
ssh -tt tester2 'screen -d -m sudo -u mysql innobackupex  --stream=tar --databases="sampledb" /mysql-backup/prodfullbkp | nc -w 30 tester 5555'
```

While the two above commands are not working when running from deploy machine.Could someone please help me give any better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a better solution like

```
ssh user@host << EOF
  #command to excecute
EOF
```

ie tester1 would be

```
ssh -tt mysql@tester1 << EOF
   screen -d -m nc -l -w 60 5555 | tar xvif -
EOF
```

tester2 would be

```
ssh -tt tester2 << EOF
   screen -d -m sudo -u mysql innobackupex  --stream=tar --databases="sampledb" /mysql-backup/prodfullbkp | nc -w 30 tester 5555
EOF
```